# Batch export xml files to csv using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, csv, xml-parsing

I am new to python so please bear with me with silly questions
I have multiple xml in the following format and I would like to extract certain tags within those xmls and export them to a single csv file.

Here is an example of the xml (c:\xml\1.xml)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="emotionStyleSheet_template.xsl"?>
<EmotionReport>
    <VersionInformation>
        <Version>8.2.0</Version>
    </VersionInformation>
    <DateTime>
        <Date>18-10-2021</Date>
        <Time>14-12-26</Time>
    </DateTime>
    <SourceInformation>
        <File>
            <FilePath>//nas/emotionxml</FilePath>
            <FileName>file001.mxf</FileName>
            <FileSize>9972536969</FileSize>
            <FileAudioInformation>
                <AudioDuration>1345.0</AudioDuration>
                <SampleRate>48000</SampleRate>
                <NumChannels>8</NumChannels>
                <BitsPerSample>24</BitsPerSample>
                <AudioSampleGroups>64560000</AudioSampleGroups>
                <NumStreams>8</NumStreams>
                <Container>Undefined Sound</Container>
                <Description>IMC Nexio
</Description>
                <StreamInformation>
                    <Stream>
                        <StreamNumber>1</StreamNumber>
                        <NumChannelsInStream>1</NumChannelsInStream>
                        <Channel>
                            <ChannelNumber>1</ChannelNumber>
                            <ChannelEncoding>PCM</ChannelEncoding>
                        </Channel>
                    </Stream>
                    <Stream>
                        <StreamNumber>2</StreamNumber>
                        <NumChannelsInStream>1</NumChannelsInStream>
                        <Channel>
                            <ChannelNumber>1</ChannelNumber>
                            <ChannelEncoding>PCM</ChannelEncoding>
                        </Channel>
                    </Stream>
                </StreamInformation>
                <FileTimecodeInformation>
                    <FrameRate>25.00</FrameRate>
                    <DropFrame>false</DropFrame>
                    <StartTimecode>00:00:00:00</StartTimecode>
                </FileTimecodeInformation>
            </FileAudioInformation>
        </File>
    </SourceInformation>
</EmotionReport>
```

expect output result (EmotionData.csv)

```
,Date,Time,FileName,Description,FileSize,FilePath
0,18-10-2021,14-12-26,file001.mxf,IMC Nexio,9972536969,//nas/emotionxml
1,13-10-2021,08-12-26,file002.mxf,IMC Nexio,3566536770,//nas/emotionxml
2,03-10-2021,02-09-21,file003.mxf,IMC Nexio,46357672,//nas/emotionxml
....
```

Here is the code I've wrote based on what I've learned from online resources (emotion_xml_parser.py):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import glob2
import pandas as pd

cols = ["Date", "Time", "FileName", "Description", "FileSize", "FilePath"]
rows = []
for filename in glob2.glob(r'C:\xml\*.xml'):
  xmlData = ET.parse(filename)
  rootXML = xmlData.getroot()
  for i in rootXML:
    Date = i.findall("Date").text
    Time = i.findall("Time").text
    FileName = i.findall("FileName").text
    Description = i.findall("Description").text
    FileSize = i.findall("FileSize").text
    FilePath = i.findall("FilePath").text

    row.append({"Date": Date,
                "Time": Time,
                "FileName": FileName,
                "Description": Description,
                "FileSize": FileSize,
                "FilePath": FilePath,})
df = pd.DataFrame(rows,columns = cols)

# Write dataframe to csv
df.to_csv("EmotionData.csv")
```

I am receiving the following error when running the script

```
  File "c:\emtion_xml_parser.py", line 14, in <module>
    Date = i.findall("Date").text
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

TIA!

Comment: `findall()` returns a list of xml elements. You will need to choose one element in this list to access its `text` attribute. If you know there's only one `Date` tag, you can use `i.find("Date").text` instead of `findall()`.

Comment: @rchome i tried using find() initially and i got the following error:
`File "c:\emtion_xml_parser.py", line 13, in <module>
    Date = i.find("Date").text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`
and those tag names i am after is unique in xml

Comment: I see, so some files may not have a `Date` tag. Is that correct?

Comment: @rchome I have duplicated 3 copies of the example file which i can confirm they all they have those tags in them.

Comment: Have you tried [beautifulsoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) ?

Comment: no, I've heard good things about the beautifulsoup module. will look into it. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better approach is to give the full path to each element you need, for example:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import glob2
import pandas as pd

cols = ["Date", "Time", "FileName", "Description", "FileSize", "FilePath"]
rows = []

for filename in glob2.glob(r'*.xml'):
    xmlData = ET.parse(filename)
    root = xmlData.getroot()
  
    row = {
        'Date' : root.findtext('DateTime/Date'),
        'Time' : root.findtext('DateTime/Time'),
        'FileName' : root.findtext('SourceInformation/File/FileName'),
        'Description' : root.findtext('SourceInformation/File/FileAudioInformation/Description').strip(),
        'FileSize' : root.findtext('SourceInformation/File/FileSize'),
        'FilePath' : root.findtext('SourceInformation/File/FilePath')
    }

    rows.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)

# Write dataframe to csv
df.to_csv("EmotionData.csv")
```

Giving you:

```
,Date,Time,FileName,Description,FileSize,FilePath
0,18-10-2021,14-12-26,file001.mxf,IMC Nexio,9972536969,//nas/emotionxml
```

Comment: great, this is working for me. Thank you.
Could you please explain to me a little more of what "row = {}" does? the curly braces is used to define dictionary in python but in this case its empty?

Comment: It creates an empty dictionary so it can be used in the next lines

Comment: You could also just create the entries directly in one go but sometimes extra code is needed when extracting values